# Cannot get objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, object

[image]

I am using a web service that return a JSON object. I need help in getting access to nested objects.

JSON is validated and valid as you can see in picture.
I am using `result.GetArticlesByTagsResult.Articles.Article[0].id`, but I get `undefined` all the time. I've tried almost possible combinations.

Please, I'm new to JSON and I can't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is `result`? what's inside Article[0]? can't see from the screenshot. `id` may be undefined

Comment: before you can access JSON object you must use `var myResults = JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: ID is defined. If i use var myResults = JSON.parse(result)  i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o  as json is allready there.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "proxy.php",
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'page': pageN},
            success: function (result) {
                showResults(result);

            },

Comment: PHP CODE    $url = "http://ws.cinema.sapo.pt/GetArticlesByTags?Dossier=oscares-2014&Tags=noticia&PageNumber=7";
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo json_encode($xml);

Comment: this is the json:   {"GetArticlesByTagsResult":{"Articles":{"Article":[{"Id":"5806",....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, the property is `Id`, not `id`

Try `result.GetArticlesByTagsResult.Articles.Article[0].Id`

Comment: Thank you. I know that some stupid thing like that would be.